# Manejo de @ExceptionHandler - Proyecto Spring Java

Tags: java

soy estudiante de programación, estoy desarrollando una API en Spring.
En este controller tengo el endpoint ("/update"). Que tiene su anotación @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED) para cuando la operación es exitosa. Pero en caso de que se lance excepción se llama al método **IdNotFoundResponse** que está anotado con @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) y @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND). Haciendo pruebas cuando se ingresa un Id que no se encuentra en la BBDD se lanza la exception definida para este caso, ingresa al método correcto, pero el código de respuesta Http que se recibe es HttpStatus.ACCEPTED y no HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND que sería lo deseado.
Dejo a continuación el código del controller,

Muchas gracias por todos sus aportes!

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clients")

public class ClientController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;        

    
    private ClientConverter clientConverter = new ClientConverter();
    
    @GetMapping("/create")
    public ClientDTO createClient(String name, String email, String phone){
        Client client = clientService.create(name, email, phone); 
        clientService.add(client);
        ClientDTO clientDTO = clientConverter.clienToClientDTO(client);
        return clientDTO;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)    
    public List<Client> getAll(){
    return clientService.getAll();        
    }    
    
    @GetMapping("/find-id/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ClientDTO getById(@PathVariable int id){
        return clientService.getById(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/find-name/{name}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Client> getByName(@PathVariable String name){
        return clientService.getByName(name);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/find-email/{email}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Client> getByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
        return clientService.getByEmail(email);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/save")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Client saveClient(@RequestBody Client client){
        return clientService.save(client);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void updateClient(@RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO){
        try {
            clientService.update(clientDTO);           
        } catch (NonClientException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            IdNotFoundResponse(e);
        } catch (Exception e){
            IdNotFoundResponse(e);
        }
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public void IdNotFoundResponse(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());      
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String errorReponse(Exception e) {
        String message = "Se ha producido un error";
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que estás capturando tú la excepción en lugar de dejar que lo haga Spring.

Creo que esto debería funcionarte

```
@PutMapping("/update")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void updateClient(@RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO){
    clientService.update(clientDTO);
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public void handleException(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());      
}
```

Como podrás ver he quitado el bloque try-catch de tu método `update`, ahí es donde tú capturabas la excepción pero la idea de la etiqueta `@ExceptionHandler` es dejar que la excepción la capture el método marcado. También he modificado el nombre de tu método `IdNotFoundResponse` porque no sigue las convenciones de java: los métodos no deben empezar por mayúscula y deben empezar por un verbo, pues son acciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto ha funcionado! Solo tuve que agregar al método updateClient la cláusula throws NonClientException. Agradezco también los consejos sobre la buenas practicas las he tenido en cuenta!
Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas otro controlador.
creas un controlador con la anotacion
@RestControllerAdvice
para un not Content que seria un 204 (que es erroneamene lo que has puesto como not found error 404)
puedes creaar algo asi

```
   @ExceptionHandler(NotContentInditex.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> itemNotFoundHandler(NotContentInditex ex) {
    logger.error("Error 204: {}", ex.getMensaje());
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
  }
```

y la clase siendo algo asi

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class NotContentInditex extends RuntimeException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
  private final int codigoError;
  private final String mensaje;

  public NotContentInditex(int codigoError, String mensaje) {
    this.codigoError = codigoError;
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
  }
}
```

en los metodos del controller eliminas los try cath y tp puedes poner throw exception

Comment: Muchas gracias, había visto una opción parecida con un ExceptioHandler global pero no logre hacerla funcionar. Requiero mas estudio para implementar está solución ya que hay elementos del código que no conozco como @Data, @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) y el logger.
De todas formas he tenido en cuenta la sugerencia del código de respuesta y lo he he cambiado por el 204.
Saludos,

Comment: @data y el  @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) es una anotacion de lombok sustituye los getter y los seter y la 2ª al equals y el hascode.Te ahorras codigo el logger es simplemente como un print para que aparea el texto por consola.

Lo dlerror tu ten en cuenta que aunque no encuentre nada la llamada es correcta por lo que no puede ser un error 404 tiene que ser 200 porque la llamada es correcta